# Does the permission check the group or individual permissions?

Tags: python, django

so I have been having a small confusion regarding permissions. All my tables are made in the app called `app`. And each *admin user* is assigned to a specific group, which is shown below.

[image]

Similarly for every page, depending on the user's permission they would be able to access different pages. And for every view, there is a custom decorator as shown.

[image: 2nd pic]

Which has the code written in a separate `decorators.py` file.

```
def permissions_allowed(allowed=[]):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not request.user.is_staff:
                messages.warning(request, "403 FORBIDDEN: You are not authorized to view the admin page!")
                return redirect('home')

            
            for perm in allowed:
                if not request.user.has_perm(perm):
                    messages.warning(request, "You don't have the permissions to complete this action. Please contact the admin!")
                    return redirect ('adminHome')

            return view_func (request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator
```

So my questions:

1. Is my syntax to check the permission correct? (as shown in the 2nd pic)
2. When I use `request.user.has_perm()` does it check the group permissions? the individual permissions? or both of them?

Please let me know what I am doing wrong since the code isn't running the way I want it to.

Thanks!

Comment: What I read is you test user's permission first, then for each user in your list, raise a warning and stop the loop as soon as one of them has `has_perm(x) == False` (we don't know what `has_perm()` method is) without checking the others.
If I understand your objective, you should rather check that a user is within one authorized group, but not check each group member

Comment: @Christophe Not really, what I need when I run the code `request.user.has_perm(perm)` I want to check the group *and* user permissions collectively and then give or deny access to a specific page

Comment: Well, anyway I do not really see checks at group level, only all members within a group. In my opinion, the group should support rights, and as soon as a user is in the group, he is authorized. Of coursed, there can be some cases where individual rights can be necessary in complement. But, in your case, it looks like there are no rights managed at group level

Comment: OK sorry, I didn't notice `has_perm()` is a standard Django method. But it's defined at user level, so the answer is definitively: no, there is no check at group level with this syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm) `has_perm()` method checks permission at user's level:

> Returns **True** if the user has the specified permission, where perm is in the format `<app label>.<permission codename>`. (see documentation on permissions). If the user is inactive, this method will always return **False**. For an active superuser, this method will always return **True**.

Thus, if you want to check permission at group level, you can retrieve them using [`get_group_permissions()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_group_permissions):

> Returns a set of permission strings that the user has, through their groups.

You can also consider using `get_all_permissions()` to gather all permission (at user and group level).

In your case, you already check the standard attribute `user.is_staff`, so if you stored the group id to consider, checking groups permission will maybe make more sense (there is no standard method, just a common use of a M2M relation between `Group` and `Permission` models)

Comment: small comment, U CANNOT check the group level permissions with `get_group_permissions():` but rather get all the permissions within the group.

Comment: Please do that change and I shall vote up your answer

Comment: You're right, thanks, I changed the wording accordingly